# How to reach catchError operator with testing

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to cover `catchError` blocks from my code but I tried many approaches and none of them actually works. My code is properly covered except all `catchError` blocks! Is there some magic function that I would not know ?

Here is some sample code.

**some.effects.ts**

```
 get$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(myActions.Get),
    switchMap(({ payload }) => {
      return this.httpService.get(payload).pipe(
        map(res => myActions.Loaded({ payload: res })),
        catchError(() => {
          localStorage.removeItem('someItem');
          return of(myActions.Create()))
        }
      );
    })
  )
```

);

**some.effects.spec.ts**

```
  it('get$ fails', () => {

    function mockError() {
      return new HttpErrorResponse({
        error: 'error', 
        headers: new HttpHeaders(),
        status: 404
      });
    }

    spyOn(httpService, 'get').and.returnValue(of(mockError));

    actions$ = hot('--a', { a: myActions.Get({}) });
    completion$ = cold('--c', { c: myActions.Create({}) });

    expect(effects.get$).toBeObservable(completion$);
    expect(localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

EDIT: The spec file above is just one of the many snippets I tried and I don't get why this is not working. Any advice would be mad appreciated. Also, I can get the catchError to be tested with effects.get$.subscribe but for some reason it's skipped on code coverage which is an issue for this case.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `throwError` instead of `of`

```js
spyOn(httpService, 'get').and.returnValue(throwError(mockError));
```

Comment: It works! This is insane, I have been trying throwError but not that way... Why is `spyOn(...).and.throwError()` not working?

Comment: because `.and.throwError` is part of `jasmine` that doesn't do anythiing with `rxjs`. `throwError` is a `rxjs` creation function that creates a stream that instantly throws an error on a subscription.